# Should we add a historical lock to, or delete this old upvoted question?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, obsolete-questions, locks

[This question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/48536/planning-perk-point-allocations-throughout-skyrim) about planning perk point allocation is pretty clearly off topic, however it is upvoted quite a bit (+20), has 46k+ views, and has quite a bit of good information. To delete it, it would take 5 delete votes to get rid of it, and delete votes can take a long time to come (there are a number of closed questions that are years old that still need a deletion vote). We have historically locked similar questions in the past, so the question is should we lock it or delete it? Either action will probably require a mod hammer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for the question off-topic is being opinion based. Per our guidelines, a question should be objective rather subjective to be on-topic. Even though is off-topic, it attracted many views, upvotes, and overall good information for future viewers.

From what I have seen, an off-topic question may be good in general terms, but they attract downvotes solely for the fact of being off-topic. This question only has a single negative downvote.

The fact the question is 6 years old, but only closed within the past 6 months shows how many users found the information useful, despite being off-topic. If the question is deleted, then the information will be lost without the proper privileges

My vote is have a moderator cast the historical lock on the question. The question matches 3 out the 4 [criteria for a good historical lock candidate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126587/what-is-a-historical-lock-and-what-is-it-used-for).

> 1. The post does not meet the current guidelines for a good, on-topic question, **and**
> 2. The post is stellar, in spite of its off-topic nature, **and**
> 3. There are a large number of views, upvotes and inbound links on the post

The fourth criteria states the question should be go through a cycle of close/open or delete/undelete at least once. However, a comment mentions users frequently desire questions to be locked without being reopened or undeleted. In this case, I am one of those users.

Comment: This was my thought as well. It has good info, but is off topic for our site. I had raised a mod flag on it that was marked as helpful, but nothing was done, so I figured I'd ask the community for input.

Comment: @Dragonrage Good call. Now we wait and see what other users have to say

Comment: Agreed, and done, for the reasons stated in this answer :-)